# Why does WPF application not react correctly on DialogResult value if System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog is used in this WPF application?

Tags: wpf, winforms, mvvm, folderbrowserdialog

I use `System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog` instance in my WPF MVVM application. Please see the following code from the View Model:

```
. . . . . . . .
using System.Windows.Forms;
. . . . . . . .
FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
DialogResult res = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (res == DialogResult.OK)
{
   this.PathToExcelExportRepository = string.Copy(dialog.SelectedPath);
   this.IsTurnOffExportToExcelSelected = false;
   this.IsTurnOnExportToExcelSelected = true;
   . . . . . . . . .
}
```

Where `IsTurnOffExportToExcelSelected` is:

```
   public bool IsTurnOffExportToExcelSelected
   {
        get { return this._isTurnOffExportToExcelSelected; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._isTurnOffExportToExcelSelected, value); }
   }
```

and `IsTurnOnExportToExcelSelected` is:

```
public bool IsTurnOnExportToExcelSelected
{
   get { return this._isTurnOnExportToExcelSelected; }
   set { this.SetProperty(ref this._isTurnOnExportToExcelSelected, value); }
}
```

Each one of these properties is binding source fore menu item in the View:

```
<telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
   <telerik:RadContextMenu>
       <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Turn on export to MS Excel" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsTurnOnExportToExcelSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Command="{Binding TurnOnExportToExcelCommand}"/>
       <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Turn off export to MS Excel" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding IsTurnOffExportToExcelSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Command="{Binding TurnOffExportToExcelCommand}"/>
   </telerik:RadContextMenu>
</telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
```

The condition of if-statement above is satisfied if `DialogResult` is `DialogResult.OK`. I verify it to set breakpoint in debugger. But if I click 'Cancel' button in the dialog then the debugger doesn't not show next steps but `IsChecked` property of `IsTurnOnExportToExcelSelected` menu item is set to `true` (the status of `IsChecked` property of `TurnOffExportToMSExcel` menu item is not changed). Why is `TurnOnExportToMSExcel` boolean property set to true if `DialogResult` is `Cancel`?

*As **wkl** suggested I show here the source code of `TurnOnExportToExcelCommand`. It turns on export to CSV-file of the values of real-time chart data-points:*

```
// This line is in the View Model constructor.
this.TurnOnExportToExcelCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.turnOnExportToExcel);

// This is the command definition in the View Model.
public DelegateCommand TurnOnExportToExcelCommand { get; private set; }

    private void turnOnExportToExcel()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult res = dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.PathToExcelExportRepository = string.Copy(dialog.SelectedPath);

            this.IsTurnOffExportToExcelSelected = false;
            this.IsTurnOnExportToExcelSelected = true;
            // Define for which chart (absolute or relative) export to CSV-file is turned on.
            if (this.IsAbsoluteSplineChartSelected || this.IsAbsoluteBarChartSelected)
            {
                // Export of absolute chart data-point to CSV-file:
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this._isAbsoluteChartDataBeingExported, 1, 0);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(this.peekAbsoluteDataForExportToCsv, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(this.exportToCsvAbsoluteChartPoints, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                // Export absolute chart data-point values is turned on.
                GlobalStaticMembers.ChartsExportToExcelStatus[0] = true;
            }
            else if (this.IsComparativeSplineChartSelected || this.IsComparativeBarChartSelected)
            {
                // Export of relative chart data-point to CSV-file:
                Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this._isComparativeChartDataBeingExported, 1, 0);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(this.peekComparativeDataForExportToCsv, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(this.exportToCsvComparativeChartPoints, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                // Export relative chart data-point values is turned on.
                GlobalStaticMembers.ChartsExportToExcelStatus[1] = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need, then I'll give you source code of method that are called from this command: peekAbsoluteDataForExportToCsv, exportToCsvAbsoluteChartPoints, peekComparativeDataForExportToCsv, exportToCsvComparativeChartPoints.

Comment: I suggest you set a break point in the setter of `IsTurnOnExportToExcelSelected` and examine the stack trace.

Comment: What do `TurnOnExportToExcelCommand` and `SetProperty` do? Could you add their definitions to your question, please?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense as it stands right now. It is not providing the necessary information in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I don't have telerik, but doesn't `IsCheckable="True"` enable checking by click even when no command is executed or the code behind doesn't touch the check property? Meaning, when `res == DialogResult.OK` is `false`, the check properties are not updated in code and therefore only the property of the current menu button is inverted?

Comment: grek40, do you know how to protect this wrong situation?

Comment: First of all, please start a comment for me with `@Grek40` so I will be notified. Then, how about __not__ setting `IsCheckable="True"`? I suppose it is not required for setting `IsChecked` from code, but only to enable automatic checking on user click... try it.

Comment: I add 'else' condition statement 'else if (res == DialogResult.Cancel){...}' and now my code works good.